# NoClassDefFoundError for com.sun.xml.tree.XmlDocument

Tags: java, xml

I am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when i `import com.sun.xml.tree.XmlDocument`. I am unable to find to find the correct jar which i need to refer to?

Comment: Which java are you using? Oracle/sun at least used to have it, other java's probably not. It's proprietary code. Search for a suitable replacement.

Comment: You should not be relying on anything in the com.sun.* package. The sun.* packages are not part of the supported, public interface. 

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html

Comment: I am using java 1.8.0.291

Comment: There's no such jar, you will have to migrate code. That package might have been available on old JREs. Read FAQs suggested by @Mihail

Comment: Remove that `import` statement.  Whatever you are trying to do, you can do it without relying on com.sun.* packages, which are not meant to be used by developers.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your code relies on private classes (implementation) of the Oracle JDK. To stick to the standard and enjoy the "compile once run everywhere" paradigm, you need to rely on classes that are published as [API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/index.html).

Comment: I am working on legacy code which is implemented in 1990s and trying to make it work for now before i update the code with recent versions. So looking for an option with correct jar file which i can successful run without NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Check the date when your code was created. Then find out what Oracle Jave version was up to date then. Try to install that, or get it's source code to at least have the java class.